# separate output element in Sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I wrote a simple program to calculate the intersection point between a line and a plane in Sympy. It works well and the answer is correct but I don't know how to get the first output element (7/5). Is there a way to print the first element? (print 7/5)

```
from sympy import  Line3D, Plane,Point3D
a = Plane(Point3D(0, 0, 1), normal_vector=(0, 0, 1))
c = Line3D(Point3D(1, 1, 5), Point3D(2, 1, -5))
print c.intersection(a)[0]
```

Comment: What is the first element? Try `print c.intersection(a)`

Comment: the first element is 7/5

Comment: I didn't mean the value of the 1st element...

Comment: the first element is 7/5, the second and the third are 1. How is it possible to print only the numbers ?

Comment: Have you already tried my proposal in the very first comment?

Comment: Yes, of course, but it prints the whole term. '[Point3D(7/5,1,1)]'. I just want the numbers to use them for other works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90228/discussion-between-user3109979-and-alex-s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print c.intersection(a)[0].x
```

Docs: http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/geometry/point3d.html